# HTML input width with Bootstrap@5 form-control

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Using [`Bootstrap@5.3`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/), is it possible to specify the `input` width using [`form-control`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/form-control/) or [`input-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/input-group/)?

Consider the example below, where I need the width of every `input` to be relevant to its `maxlength`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <label for="mygroup" class="form-label">Numbers</label>
  <div class="input-group has-validation mb-2" id="mygroup">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="11" pattern="^\d{1,11}$" required placeholder="Number" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" minlength="7" maxlength="15" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" placeholder="IP" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" min="1" max="65535" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="8" min="1" max="16777215" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" min="1" max="65535" required />
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telephone-plus-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.885.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.61.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511zM12.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V3h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H13v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4h-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H12V1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/></svg></button>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter valid number</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxlength` - this is not a style property.
But you can do something like this:

```css
#mygroup input[maxlength="11"] {
  flex: 11;
}
#mygroup input[maxlength="7"] {
  flex: 7;
}
#mygroup input[maxlength="5"] {
  flex: 5;
}
#mygroup input[maxlength="8"] {
  flex :8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <label for="mygroup" class="form-label">Numbers</label>
  <div class="input-group has-validation mb-2" id="mygroup">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="11" pattern="^\d{1,11}$" required placeholder="Number" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="7" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" placeholder="IP" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" min="1" max="65535" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="8" min="1" max="16777215" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" min="1" max="65535" required />
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telephone-plus-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.885.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.61.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511zM12.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V3h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H13v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4h-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H12V1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/></svg></button>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter valid number</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or this:

```css
#mygroup {
  display: grid!important;
  grid-template-columns: 11fr 7fr 5fr 8fr 5fr auto;
}

#mygroup input {
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <label for="mygroup" class="form-label">Numbers</label>
  <div class="input-group has-validation mb-2" id="mygroup">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="11" pattern="^\d{1,11}$" required placeholder="Number" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="7" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" placeholder="IP" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" min="1" max="65535" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="8" min="1" max="16777215" required />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" min="1" max="65535" required />
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telephone-plus-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.885.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.61.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511zM12.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V3h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H13v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4h-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H12V1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/></svg></button>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter valid number</div>
  </div>
</div>
```